# Can apply for UK visitor visa from a country that I have temporary visa in?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, sudanese-citizens

Hello I am a Sudanese doctor applying for UK visitor visa for my PLAB 2 exam in 24 of October 2023.  I am currently on my visa application and one of the doccuments is that I have to prove legal entry and visa from the country I am applying from which is Saudi Arabia.I am a visitor in Saudi Arabia (1 year family visa with multiple entry).

My problem is that my visa document clearly states that I have 90 days to reside in Saudi Arabia, then I have to leave and come back again. *multiple entry* I applied for the visa to be granted on 24 of September (1 month before my exam) and my 90 days here ends on 24 August. I can choose to renew my stay but it has to be 1 week before it expires or I can exit to any country and travel back to be given another 3 months

Will this be a problem in my UK visa application?
Should I explain the multiple entry visa I have and its rules? Or will it definitely going to cause me a rejection?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the immigration status in Saudi Arabia you describe should not cause an automatic refusal. Explaining the rules relating to your Saudi Arabian visitor visa in your UK application would be a sensible approach, alongside providing evidence of ties *to your country of residence*.

From *Entry clearance* https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk

> 27. An application for entry clearance is to be decided in the light of the circumstances existing at the time of the decision, except that an applicant will not be refused an entry clearance where entry is sought in one of the categories contained in paragraphs 296-316 or paragraph EC-C of Appendix FM solely on account of his attaining the age of 18 years between receipt of his application and the date of the decision on it.

> 28. An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom and Islands at the time of the application. An application for an entry clearance as a visitor or as a short-term student or under Appendix Ukraine Scheme must be made to any post designated by the Secretary of State to accept such applications.

See also *Note on PLAB refusals* in [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: Hello thank you for replying to my question with these helpful answers and links.. another questions arise..I have no ties to the country I am residing in other than my family after 're relocated together Beacuse the war in my country  will that be sufficient? Or the fact that I relocated due to war is another reason for refusal, also I have checked the plab visa refusal on the link you have provided. It clearly state that ppl who havens started an independent lifestyle after graduation is a common reason for refusal . Although I have graduated in 2020 completed my internship training..tbc

Comment: And I have started working as a general practitioner in the ER in a hospital since November and booked for plab2 immediately after suceededing plab1,

Comment: But I was unable to get letter of employment or extract my bank statement as I was came upon us suddenly in Sudan. Which makes me equal to a fresh graduate with no experience. Should I mention this in my cover letter or is it useless as there is no evidence to support it? I have relocated with my savings and my brother sent an family invitation for us to enter Saudi Arabia after staying in Egypt for a month, but I gain I have no proof of my savings because all bank apps arnt working pass simple transactions and again war. I can't work in Saudi Arabia yet Beacuse

Comment: I have to be registered  in their medical council which requires certificate verifications from my university and my medical council In Sudan ( which currently unable to respond) is there any way to enhance my chances of getting a visa or should I not risk it with all the obstacles I have in my application?

Comment: @ElafHamed IANAL however based on your comments it’s vanishingly likely you would get the visa. Better to wait until you’ve got the qualification evidence you need and/or have regularised your immigration status outside Sudan.